# add codes to the afterclass in Junit

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

How can I add some codes to the @AfterClass method in unit test but without modifying the test source code and run it via junit cmd.
Here is my try but it does not override @AfterClass of the unit test.

```
import org.junit.runner.JUnitCore;
import org.junit.runner.Result;
import org.junit.runner.Request;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.After;
import org.uni.DumpGenerator;

public class SingleJUnitTestRunner {
    public static void main(String... args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        String classAndMethod = args[0];
    Request request = Request.aClass(Class.forName(classAndMethod));
        Result result = new JUnitCore().run(request);
    }
    @AfterClass
    public static void afterClass() throws Exception, InterruptedException {
    System.gc();
    Thread.sleep(5000L);
    DumpGenerator.dumpToFile("test", "afterRun");
    }
}
```

and then I use this cmd:
    java -cp pathtojunit SingleJUnitTestRunner Mytest

But the method afterclass does not work.
Any help!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@AfterClass` annotation applies to a test case, not a test runner. You can either apply it to each test you want to run (or the base class, for that matter), or just call it directly in your `main` function:

```
public static void main(String... args) throws Exception, ClassNotFoundException {
    String classAndMethod = args[0];
    Request request = Request.aClass(Class.forName(classAndMethod));
    Result result = new JUnitCore().run(request);
    afterClass();
}
```

Comment: This way can not affect the method in unit test which annotated by @AfterClass.